# Kendo UI Grid long date on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

In my grid I have a date column with the following parameters:

```
update: {
            url: ROOT+"user/update-user",
            type: "POST"
        }

columns: [
    {...},
    {
        field: "DoB",
        width: 68,
        title: "DoB",
        format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
        template: '#= kendo.toString(DoB,"dd/MM/yyyy") #'
    },
    {...}

datasource: {
    ...
    schema: {
        model: {
            DoB: {type: "date", editable: false, format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"},
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, is that when I try to update the date column it is sending a really long date instead of the SQL style date "YYYY-MM-DD":

```
Wed Jan 09 2003 00:00:00 GMT +0000 etc
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: I can't help but find it funny that someone edited this post to change "I try" to "i try"...

Comment: I'm some sort of confused. In your code you show the `column` definition for field "DoB", while in you `model` you show `dateStarted` (that by the way is not editable). Would you mind clarify which field is the problem and include the column/model definition for it? BTW: Showing your `transport.update` definition might also be convenient.

Comment: @OnaBai Sorry, I have corrected the column name and added my update definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because when KendoUI is about to send data to the server it serializes your data to `string` and default serialization for `date` type is the long format.

You can adapt you data for sending it to the server by defining a `transport.update` as:

```
update: {
    url : ROOT + "user/update-user",
    type: "POST",
    data: function (data) {
        data.DoB = kendo.toString(data.DoB, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        return data;
    }
},
```

**NOTE** you might need some extra validation for making sure that `DoB` is actually defined